# Can't draw in Clock Callback in Kivy

Tags: android, python, kivy

I'm using the nifty Kivy framework to program a game for Android.
I'm trying to create a clock callback to run a specified piece of code (used to draw) 60 times a second.

For some reason, anything I draw inside of a Kivy clock event doesn't get drawn to the screen. To eliminate all variables I could, I took this sample code:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.6')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse


class MyPaintWidget(Widget):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        with self.canvas:
            Color(1, 1, 0)
            d = 30.
            Ellipse(pos=(touch.x - d/2, touch.y - d/2), size=(d, d))


class MyPaintApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyPaintWidget()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyPaintApp().run()
```

This works fine - when I click on the screen it puts a yellow circle there.
However, when I modify it like this:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.6')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse
from kivy.clock import Clock


class MyPaintWidget(Widget):
    def update(self, t):
        with self.canvas:
            Color(1, 1, 0)
            d = 30.
            Ellipse(pos=(200 - d/2, 200 - d/2), size=(d, d))


class MyPaintApp(App):
    def build(self):
        m = MyPaintWidget()
        Clock.schedule_interval(m.update, 1.)
        return m


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyPaintApp().run()
```

Nothing is ever drawn to the screen. Why?
EDIT: I found out it only draws to the screen when I click it. Still not useful - I need to use this for a game's event loop!
I am using Kivy 1.4.0 (the second most recent) and Ubuntu. This also doesn't work as intended on Android, either.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of kivy (latest release or git)? I tried your second script and it works for me. Also, what plateform are you using?

Comment: I'm on Kivy 1.4.0, Windows, Python 2.7 and the second script allows me to righ-click and it will then draw a circle that follows the mouse around until I release the button. I can left-click to select circles to move then, or just click and release to have them disappear.

Answer (score 1):

I can run your code - I've made a bit of a change so you can see that it is indeed being called every second. It now prints out the value of D, that changes every second, and the big yellow circle grows each second. I hope this helps you.

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.6')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse
from kivy.clock import Clock

class MyPaintWidget(Widget):
    d = 10
    def update(self, t):
        print("D is", self.d)
        with self.canvas:
            Color(1, 1, 0)
            self.d = self.d + 1
            Ellipse(pos=(200 - self.d/2, 200 - self.d/2), size=(self.d, self.d))


class MyPaintApp(App):
    def build(self):
        m = MyPaintWidget()
        Clock.schedule_interval(m.update, 1.)
        return m


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyPaintApp().run()
```